# creating android text-based game

Tags: android

I am thinking about creating a text-based game (similar to gamebooks) for android device. In this moment only theoretically. Do you have some advice please, which way to go?

You probably know how gamebooks works, but the gamebook I want, will be very easy, should work like this:

User has shown some image, text and 3 options (questions), he decides which option to click, then a new page is showing (according to the clicked option) with another image, text and another 3 options. Then again, the user clicks one option, another page opens, etc.

My question is not how to do it programmatically, but how to start with this in Android Studio, what system to use for such game on android or which way to go.

Because I think it has no sense to create intents after each click, as there might be hundreds of clickable options.

I have already created such game on my website with php/html/js, but I want to create it also offline for android.

Comment: You're not that new here so you should already know. opinion based or recommendation questions don't belong here. I've given you some direction to get started, but you need to do your own research, make an attempt and come back with a [mcve] once you have a concrete problem

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, I just wanted to be sure to avoid start something, what has no sense, e.g. is unmaintainable as you wrote with intents. Thanks at least for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intents implies one activity per page - unmaintainable.

You should work with a database and load based on user interaction. So you'll need to learn about Databases and Asynchronicity (working in the background while updating the UI so the user knows)